# Connect Aironet to Catalyst Switch

Tags: cisco-catalyst

I have a Cisco Aironet 2602E-A-K running 12.4(25e)JA1 with a Gig ethernet port defined as so:

```
interface GigabitEthernet0
 no ip address
 no ip route-cache
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0.1
 encapsulation dot1Q 1 native
 no ip route-cache
 bridge-group 1
 bridge-group 1 spanning-disabled
 no bridge-group 1 source-learning
!
interface GigabitEthernet0.10
 encapsulation dot1Q 10
 no ip route-cache
 bridge-group 10
 bridge-group 10 spanning-disabled
 no bridge-group 10 source-learning
```

...which I am trying to connect to a Catalyst 2948G-GE-TX running CatOS 8.4(11)GLX, the port configured as so:

```
clear trunk 2/27 2-9,11-1005,1025-4094
set trunk 2/27 nonegotiate dot1q 1,10
```

There is a Cisco 341-0212-01 Power Injector in between the two devices.

The intent is to have one SSID traverse VLAN1, and a separate SSID to traverse VLAN10.

The Aironet won't bring its Gb port up.  The Catalyst thinks the port is down.

I have tried trunk modes on, desired, and auto as well.

I have swapped all network cables involved (short of the drop between the Aironet and the wiring closet).

If I put a dumb switch in between the Catalyst and the Injector, it comes up and I can use VLAN 1.

I can configure a laptop to talk on VLAN 1 on this drop on the Catalyst.

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong, or how to get either end to tell me what they think is going wrong?

Comment: When you put in the dumb switch, do you get a link on the port connected to the injector? Also, try to put the dumb switch between the injector and the AP. You should get a link on the injector side. If not, then you have a bad injector.

Comment: Also, try setting the port speed on both ends to 100/half. If that works, then you have some bad cabling somewhere.

Comment: If I plug my laptop into the Aironet side of the injector, I can see the network through it.

Comment: Forcing the port on the catalyst to 100M fixes the problem.  So I presume that I have a wiring problem somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the port speed on both ends to 100/half. If that works, then you have some bad cabling somewhere.